# Projectile motion in two and three dimensions question?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, kinematics

So I bought this book in the library and physics fascinates me and I found this quote in the book " Galileo has proved that when any effects due to air resistance
are ignored, the ranges for projectiles (on a level field) whose angles
of projection exceed or fall short of 45° by the same amount are
equal.This can be easily proved" I don't understand it at all? And I don't think it is that easy to prove, but I want to know it so much :/ Can you explain this to me?

Answer (score 2):

You don't say how far you've got in studying physics. If you know the [SUVAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#SUVAT_equations) equations then there's a nice explanation of how to calculate the range at the [Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/traj.html#tra4) web site.

If the projectile is launched at an angle $\theta$ the range is proportional to $\sin(2\theta)$, and the function $y = \sin(2\theta)$ is symmetric about $\theta = 45^\circ$ i.e. $\sin(2(45 - \delta)) = \sin(2(45 + \delta))$ for any angle $\delta$. That's why the range is the same whether you add or subtract the angle $\delta$ to your 45$^\circ$ launch angle.